# Nautilus : "Send via Bluetooth" in Context Menu

Tags: nautilus, files, bluetooth, transfer

I use nautilus as my default file manager. Very frequently I need to transfer files to other devices via bluetooth. Is there some way to add a "Send Via Bluetooth" option in the right click context menu for a selected file, or for a selection of multiple files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've same question, waiting for answer!

Comment: you can use [nautilus-send-to-bluetooth](https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/nautilus-send-to-bluetooth) extension.

Answer (score 1):

There is this script [sec.Bluetooth.SendFile.NautilusScript.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/d3779fcf9baff69268a694ed8250adcff0ab6604/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/sec.Bluetooth.SendFile.NautilusScript.sh)

You have to copy it to `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/`

And may need to install [its latest dependencies](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/) too.

Comment: This didn't work for me on 15.04.  I installed the script, the unrelated debian package, and all the dependencies, but still no option appears. :-(

Comment: @tudor can you run any other custom nautilus script? I mean some script you create by hand just to test if it is working. Btw my nautilus version is 3.10.1,  and I use the LTS 14.04. May be the custom scripts path has changed for your version?